# combine pandas rows based on condition of columns (vectorized)

Tags: python, pandas, text, vectorization

I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[None, None, "hello1","hello2", None,"hello4","hello5","hello6", None, "hello8", None,"hello10",None ] , "b": ["we", "are the world", "we", "love", "the", "world", "so", "much", "and", "dance", "every", "day", "yeah"]})

    a   b
0   None    we
1   None    are the world
2   hello1  we
3   hello2  love
4   None    the
5   hello4  world
6   hello5  so
7   hello6  much
8   None    and
9   hello8  dance
10  None    every
11  hello10 day
12  None    yeah
```

The desired output is:

```
    a       b       new_text
0   Intro   we      we are the world
2   hello1  we      we
3   hello2  love    love the
5   hello4  world   world
6   hello5  so      so
7   hello6  much    much and
9   hello8  dance   dance every
11  hello10 day     day yeah
```

I have a function that does it, but it uses while in pandas which is probably not the best solution.

```
def connect_rows_on_condition(df, new_col_name, text, condition):
    if df[condition][0] == None:
        df[condition][0] = "Intro" 
    df[new_col_name] = ""
    index = 1
    last_non_none = 0
    while index < len(df):
        if df[condition][index] != None:
            last_non_none = index
            df[new_col_name][last_non_none] = df[text][index]

        elif df[condition][index] == None :
            df[new_col_name][last_non_none] = df[text][last_non_none] + " " + df[text][index]

        index += 1 

    output_df = df[df[condition].isna() == False]
    return output_df
```

The main logic is, if in column "a" is a None put the text in b into the row before.
Is there a solution that is not based on loops?

Answer (score 2):

First, create a Series which describes the groups:

```
grouping = df.a.notnull().cumsum()
```

Then, for column a we can use the first element and for column b we want to concatenate all elements:

```
df.groupby(grouping).agg({'a': 'first', 'b': ' '.join})
```

This gives:

```
         a                 b
a                           
0     None  we are the world
1   hello1                we
2   hello2          love the
3   hello4             world
4   hello5                so
5   hello6          much and
6   hello8       dance every
7  hello10          day yeah
```

You can replace `None` with `"Intro"` yourself as a special case if needed, since that text doesn't occur in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the grouping by a word, in case you don't have a null value to group on by this. As to not duplicate John's solution, i'll leave it here for those that may be interested in how to do this with a non null situation:

```
In [356]: Truth = pd.to_numeric(df.a.str.contains('None') == False).cumsum() 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [357]: df.groupby(Truth)['b'].agg(list)                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[357]: 
a
0    [we, are the world]
1                   [we]
2            [love, the]
3                [world]
4                   [so]
5            [much, and]
6         [dance, every]
7            [day, yeah]
Name: b, dtype: object
```